# Appending values of json object to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to append the values of a json object(`name` & `color`)  to two input fields in a form. This is a mockup of an api call being made inside my webserver. The jQuery function takes the value of the first input field, then concatenates the url + json file location and finally makes the api call. The console shows the values are retrieved successfully but I am unsure how to append them accordingly to their input field. [SITE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/concatenate/)

Json:

```
{
    "name": "test1",
    "color": "red",
}
```

jQuery/AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /** get the inputs we might need */
  var $result = $('#result');
  var $input = $('#input');

  $result.data('url', $result.val());

  var timer;

  /** function to submit data to the server and
      update the result input on success */
  function submitForm( input, newValue) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: newValue,
      data: {input:input},
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        $result.val(newValue);
      }
    });
  };

  /** on key up, fill #result with the url + input */
  $input.bind('keyup', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var inp = $this.val();
    var url = $result.data('url');
    var newValue = url + inp + '/info.json';

    if(timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      submitForm(inp, newValue) ;
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: The ajax reponse would have the json passed to your `data` argument, so you'd need to iterate that - if the key is `name`, set the value of the name field.

Comment: `$result.val(data.name)` or `data.color` if need other

Comment: @charlietfl I tried that but nothing is being displayed

Comment: tried within success handler? SUre data coming back is what you've shown?

Comment: @charlietfl nothing shows. It is inside success handler. Check [Link](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/concatenate/) I just want `name` to display in input field with id `name` and color in input field `color`

Comment: and those are ID's used in selectors? Anser shown below would work if keys match ID's....just use `data` instead of `myobj` in the `for` loop

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for sticking around but it still not displaying anything. I placed the for loop inside the success handler and replaced `data` for `myobj` but it does not show anything.

Comment: throw a console log in success handler, or alert...is it even firing? All sounds right here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40893/discussion-between-techaddict82-and-charlietfl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is taking elements from an object (from JSON) and giving those values to an input?

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="color">
```

A basic example:

```
var myobj = {"name":"botskonet","color":"blue"}

for( k in myobj ){
    document.getElementById(k).value = myobj[k];
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFV62/)

Comment: OP already shown that ID's are differnt than json keys...not sure how this solution will help

Comment: The names don't really matter. You can use any number of ways to lookup the right field name, etc. I'm never sure how much of the sample code is just simplified for us anyway. He asked "I am trying to append the values of a json object(name & color) to two input fields in a form.", and I've given a very basic demo. I'd be happy to take it further if this isn't helpful

Comment: +1 this works great, now if I have `var myobj = {"name":"botskonet","color":"blue", "animal":"gorilla"}` and just want to display `name` and `animal` I get `getElementById` is null. How come? Is it because it is going through a for loop?